# My probation period is ending in two weeks. Suddenly a lot more recruiters are approaching me on LinkedIn. Should I worry?

Tags: interviewing, linkedin, probation

I work as a software engineer, and I don't think I have a performance issue at work. The probation review is due in two weeks. Not sure if this is just in my head or I should prepare for the worst-case scenario of being fired and start interviewing again.

Comment: The actual worst-case scenario is wasting two weeks preparing for being fired because of LinkedIn recruiters.

Comment: Are you not having regular check-ins with your manager? If there were a performance concern, wouldn't they have told you already?

Comment: I don't understand why you think getting messaged on LinkedIn implies something about your job performance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR Relax, it happens all the time**

There is no way recruiters on LinkedIn could know that you are getting fired. They are random anonymous people, it would be like your pharmacist knowing you're getting fired before you.

It is purely coincidence.
What may have happen is:

- With a few month more on the job your profile is being pick more by algorithm/recruiters
- There is an overall increase in available job positions
- Already opened position are more and more in need to be filed
- Pure coincidence.

Comment: 5th Option: It's in your head. You're noticing the recruiters more because you're worried.

Comment: 6th option: the recruiters know how long probation is at your current company and they're just hoping you'll get fired or decide to leave.

Comment: "With a few month more on the job your profile is being pick more by algorithm/recruiters" Only speculation, but it may not be only "more experience" but also because either the recruiter or the algorithm know that the contract could end after the probation period. Probation period are usually the same length within the same country/field. And as both employer *and* employee can break contract after probation period, it may be a good timing for recruiters

Comment: It may not even require the recruiters to know anything about probation periods.  Their data scooping software knows how long you have been at your current company and their analytics know that after x months y% of people are willing to entertain new offers and they automatically contact you.  There are enough people out there who want to move on after 6 months that I wouldn't be at all surprised to see a spike in contacts around that time.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't think I have a performance issue at work.

Why don't you just ask your manager? The whole idea of probation is to have regular check ins and adjust as necessary. The outcome of the probation shouldn't be surprise or secret.

Answer (score 2):

**I've noticed more recruiters as well, and I'm not in a probationary period**

This has nothing to do with your performance.  I've talked with other developers and recruiter friends and they've all noticed a big up-tick in the last few weeks.